# How to compute mid using Interpolation search with string?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, interpolation

For numbers, we can compute the probe index calculation through the equation:

`low + ((target -key[low]) * (high - low )) / (key[high] - key[low])`.

But the problem is if target and key[index] are strings.

How can we know the difference between two strings?

The approach I think:

If we consider the string as ascii number, "a" is representing 97(Dec) and "d" is representing 100, and now the difference between "a" and "d" is 3.

But what if the two strings are more longer?

How should we weight these two string?  For example "ad" and "da". If I count the weight for each character, the difference between "a" and "d" is 3, and the difference between "d" and "a" is also 3. How should I know the difference between "ad" and "da"?

Comment: I feel like I walked into the middle of a conversation.  Obviously you know what you've been working on, but you're expecting us to know also, and I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @ajb Sorry about the confusion. So I know the difference between two single characters. but I don't know the difference between two char arrays...

Comment: There's no such thing as "the difference between two char arrays".  You have to define it based on what problem you're trying to solve.  But you haven't given us any information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can't really do it with integer weights, but there is a nice match here between strings and rational numbers. Just consider every character to be a digit in base-256 (or whatever), and put a virtual radix point at the start of the string. Now you have a consistent absolute position (every thing maps somewhere between 0 and 1) and distance (just subtract), it's also useless for performance but you can approximate it.

Comment: @harold This breaks down after 3 characters.  If you use a `double` to represent the rational number, it won't work with strings whose first 4 characters are the same, and it will work badly if the first 3 characters are the same.  (`double` only carries 52 bits of precision.)  I guess you could do it with `BigDecimal` but it seems messy.

Comment: @HxH, what do you want to do with the distance ? That would dictate a lot about how the distance needs to be calculated.

Comment: @ajb Just ignore the common prefix of the lower and upper endpoint strings. Then three characters is plenty for interpolation search.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Good point.  However, your comment should make it clear that this cannot be accomplished by writing a function to "compute the distance between two strings" without knowing about the third one.  The computation will need to look at all three strings (high, low, and target) together, to determine the new index (otherwise, what if low=`"abcde"`, target=`"abcfg"`, high=`"anteater"`?  It won't work to compute "target - low" by looking just at "fg" and "de".

Comment: How exactly are strings sorted? Alphabetically? Lexicographically by Unicode code point? In the former case, is any particular collation used? Or do you need it to work with any collation?

Comment: And which queries do you need to do on the string array? Finding an exact match? Finding a position to insert a new string? Getting all strings in the array that lie between two given strings? If you are only interested in exact matches, you can calculate a hash for every string and perform interpolation search on the hashes.